# Can someone help me identify this glitter dark-blue Mega Bloks part and possible sets it's in?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I need help identifying the following part please?

It has `AM 16956 4` printed on it, in addition to the Mega Bloks logo.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have pictures of the piece at other angles? My first thought would be that this is not a lego element.

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve You're right, the second picture shows that it's a MEGABLOKS piece...

Comment: Clone brands (of LEGO) are not well enough indexed online that we can really answer the second question in the title.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

[image]

*[Set #96845 Covenant Brute Chopper.](https://www.megaconstrux.com/en-us/worlds/halo/playsets/covenant-brute-chopper)*

Build instructions ***[HERE](https://s3.megabrandsmedia.com/instructions/products/instruction-covenant-brute-chopper-96845-1957.pdf)***.